# How to do lazy loading with dynamic import - angular 8

Tags: angular

I trying to using with new syntax for lazy loading:

```
{
    path: 'mf',
    loadChildren: () => import('src/app/mf/mf.module').then(m => m.MFModule),
    canActivate: [Guard],
    data: { app: App.mf },
},
```

but i got error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/starter.module.ts 27:28
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (27:28)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     {
|         path: 'mf',
>         loadChildren: () => import('src/app/mf/mf.module').then(m => m.MFModule),
|         canActivate: [Guard],
|         data: { app: App.mf },
```

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using? (This can be found by running `ng version`)

Comment: typescript 3.4.5, when i run ng version, but in the package.json i have "typescript": "~3.4.3",

Comment: https://twitter.com/yurzui/status/1133686766504947712

Answer (score 0):

Did you change "module" field in the tsconfig.json?

```
"module": "esnext"
```

Also, I suggest you handle your deps. Some people experienced difficulties with package versions.

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm -f package-lock.json
npm install
```

Comment: is it a big project? It would be easier to help you if provide a repo for reproduction

Comment: https://github.com/yantrab/nest-angular you have to run npm i in the root for generating some client api files